# Online Web Word Office AddIn, Cannot store Cookies/Session (Chrome, Edge)

Tags: cookies, office-js, office-addins

I have developed Office.js AddIn for word. Which also supposed to work in online web word. I'm using cookie in my addin which I save using js this way:

`document.cookie = "firstrun=" + 1 + "; path=/Addin/";`

and then accessing from .Net code behind like this:

`HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["firstrun"];`

It works perfectly for windows word and also **online web** word in Mozzila Firefox browser, but doesn't store any values when using **online web** word in Chrome and MS Edge.

Couldn't really find out what is the difference. Why wouldn't chrome and edge work with addin cookies in this way? Have anyone experienced such a thing?

P.S. I've also noticed that it doesn't store any session values. after this `Session["User"] = user;` `Session["User"]`  is null in other pages. This also works perfectly in firefox.

Thanks.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I have the same problem. I can't store the ASP Net session from Chrome / Edge but it works perfectly with Firefox. Any ideas? Maybe some headers to add/remove?

Comment: @polykos I solved it. It was because I had to specify SameSite=None; when saving the cookie like this:   document.cookie = "firstrun=" + 1 + "; SameSite=None; Secure; path=/Addin/";